# Does XUL support different modality scopes?

Tags: firefox, xul

Is it possible to create a dialog using XUL (specifically in Firefox) that is:

- Always-on-top but does not blocking user interaction with a page

and/or

- Only tab modal, not window modal

?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can surely have a non blocking Dialog, but it will go to the background when you click the  window. For reference see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Adding_windows_and_dialogs):

```
window.openDialog("chrome://membees/content/dialog.xul",
    "","centerscreen=yes, all=no, titlebar=yes, chrome=yes, toolbar=yes, 
    dialog=no, resizable=no,modal=no","");
```

But if you want a bit more of control you can create a [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel) instead, and take advantage of the level property:

**level**

> Specifies whether the panel appears on top of all windows, or just on
>   top of the window the panel is in. If this attribute is not set, the
>   popup window level depends on the platform. On Linux, the default
>   value is top, otherwise, the default value is parent. If a panel has
>   one or more text fields, this attribute should not be set, otherwise
>   IME or on-screen keyboard popups will appear incorrectly. For these
>   reasons, you should avoid setting the level if not needed.

- top

> The panel is shown in front of all other normal windows, including those of other applications.

- parent

> The panel is shown just above the window the panel is in, but behind
>   other windows above it. If anchored, the child window maintains its
>   relative position to its parent window.

- floating

> The panel floats above the window the panel is in. On Mac, the panel
>   is only visible when the application is active.

To create it you have to add it to the base element `<popupset>` in your overlay, and then you open it with:

```
openPopup(anchor,position,x,y,isContextMenu,attributesOverride,triggerEvent )
```